# Rails 3: How to report error message from the controller's "create" action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, validation, exception, error-handling

In my "create" action on a form, I successfully save (1) MyObject to my local database and (2) OtherObject to a third-party database via its Ruby API. When something goes wrong with the save to the third party, I get an error in the form of a Ruby exception.

My question is: How do I stop the form submit and report the exception message to the client?

If this is not possible, what would be the best alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on whether you want to rollback your local database call, you might want to consider  using [Transactions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html). Something along these lines:

```
def create
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    @myobject = MyObject.create!(params[:myobject])
    begin
      # call third-party
    rescue Exception => e
      flash[:exception] = e.message
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback # Raise this to cause a rollback on MyObject
    end
  end
  # redirect_to or render... might have to pick depending on if you got an exception
end
```

This will store the exception message into the `flash` which you can use to display to the user. **Note** Do not store the entire `Exception` object into the `flash`, you will definitely see overflow errors if your exception objects are too big.

If you're not too concerned about rolling back the `MyObject` creation, then you can just use a simple `begin`...`rescue` similar to what I showed in my example. You may need to determine whether you want to do a `redirect_to` or `render` depending on whether an exception occurred, but you can always conditionally determine that based on whether `flash[:exception].nil?` is `true` or not.

Comment: Clarification: If the exception occurs, it will definitely occur before I attempt to save MyObject. I'm using a begin...rescue block already (that is where I catch the third-party exception), but I'm not sure how to report a message on the page from within that exception... Does that make sense?

Comment: Well, either way you're going to need to either `render` or `redirect_to` a page and on that page you could display the error you're storing in your `flash`. If you don't want to leave the page and show the exception, you'll want to submit the form using Ajax (`:remote => true` on the `form_for`) and then if an exception occurs, use a `.js.erb` file and use Javascript to display the error. Since you are in controller code, you need to respond with either a page or Javascript of some sort. Does that help any?

Comment: If you're interested in this Ajax approach, here's a really quick overview of an Ajax form in Rails: http://trevorturk.com/2010/08/24/easy-ajax-forms-with-rails-3-and-jquery/

Comment: Yes, your answer and additional comments answer my question. Thank you!